# get selected value from select form to pass value in url Django

Tags: django, forms, select, edit

I am using django 1.9.2.
I have HTML form like this:

```
 <select class="form-control" style="width:50%;" id='selectedTask' name ='selectedTask' onchange='populateProject(this.id,"selectedProject")'>
            <option value="-1" >Select your Task</option>
            {% for task in all_tasks %}
                <option value="{{task.task_id}}">{{task.task_name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
</select>
<a href="{% url 'projects:edit_task' selectedTaskId %}">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

How I can send selectedtaskId, when click edit link through href?

Thanks
Shaon

Answer (score 0):

I would create a form and submit the data on button click:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'projects:edit_task' %}">
    <select class="form-control" style="width:50%;" id='selectedTask' name ='selectedTask' onchange='populateProject(this.id,"selectedProject")'>
        <option value="-1" >Select your Task</option>
        {% for task in all_tasks %}
            <option value="{{task.task_id}}">{{task.task_name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button type="submit">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Then you can access `selectedTask` in your Django view:

```
task = request.POST.get('selectedTask')
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a nice idea But I am not receiving any value for task from view, though my url is look like 
http://localhost:8000/update_task/?selectedTeam=1&selectedTask=10&selectedProject=-1

this is my view

```
def Update_Task(request): 
    taskId = request.POST.get('selectedTask') 
    print('selectedTask= ', taskId ) 
    task = get_object_or_404(Project, task_id=taskId)
```

And this is my URL

```
url(r'^update_task/$', views.Update_Task, name='update_task'),
```